# Sufficient condition for Lebesgue integrability

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ such that
$$ 0\leq \int_\mathbb{R^d} f(x)\,d x \,<\infty \;.$$

Can I say that $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ ?

My only concern is that $f\ngeq0$. Is the non-negativity of the integral sufficient to conclude that
$$ \int_\mathbb{R^d} |f(x)|\,d x \,<\infty\quad?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int f(x)dx$ is defined only when $\int f^{+}(x)dx<\infty$ or $\int f^{-}(x)dx<\infty$. In this case $\int f(x)dx=\int f^{+}(x)dx-\int f^{-}(x)dx$ and if this is a real number then $\int f^{+}(x)dx<\infty$ **and** $\int f^{-}(x)dx<\infty$ so $\int |f(x)|dx<\infty$.

In general if $\int fd\mu$ is defined and is a real number (not $\pm \infty$) then $f$ is intergable. This is a basic feature of Lebesgue's Theory.